# How to fully display text in the text box of Manipulate control when expanded?

Tags: manipulate, text, display

When the control of Manipulate got expanded there's a display text box but it does not fully show the control value as shown in figure.  Is there any way that the size of this box can be adjusted to show the complete form of the control value?

[image: text box in Manipulate not showing the complete value]

Example to reproduce the problem:

```
Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can you provide some *minimal* code for reproducing this problem?

Comment: Only a partial solution (thus not an answer): `Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6, Appearance -> Large}]`

Comment: A partial answer literally only for this kind of case: ``Style[
 Manipulate[
  Style[x, FractionBoxOptions -> {"Beveled" -> False}],
  {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}],
 FractionBoxOptions -> {"Beveled" -> True}
 ]``

Comment: @Szabolcs your solution worked for me.  Thank you!

Comment: @JohnP It does not work well for me. Some of the bottom is still cut off.

Comment: If you turn up the magnification of the window, it may help.  On a Mac, with magnification 125% readable, and at 150% comfortable viewing.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** You can use `DefaultOptions` directly when specifying the control:

```
Manipulate[x, 
  {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6,
    Appearance -> "Open", 
    AppearanceElements -> All,
    DefaultOptions -> 
       {InputField -> {ImageSize -> {Small, 50}, Alignment -> Center}}}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can set the `ImageSize` of the `InputField` using [`DefaultOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultOptions.html) option of [`Manipulator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulator.html):

```
manipulator1 = Manipulator[##, Appearance -> "Open", 
  DefaultOptions -> {InputField -> {ImageSize -> {Small, Full}, 
    FrameMargins -> 1, Alignment -> {Left, Center}}}] &;

Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6, manipulator1}]
```

[image]

[image]

If you want to fix the height, use `InputField -> {ImageSize -> {Small, 30}`:

```
manipulator2 = Manipulator[##, Appearance -> "Open", 
   DefaultOptions -> {InputField -> {ImageSize -> {Small, 30}, 
       FrameMargins -> 1, Alignment -> {Left, Center}}}] &; 

Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6, manipulator2}]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need the full set of animation controls? Or do you only open them to be able to see and change the current value of the slider setting?

In the first case, I recommend

```
Manipulate[
  x,
  {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6,
    Appearance -> "Labeled",
    AppearanceElements ->
      {"StepLeftButton", "PlayPauseButton", "StepRightButton", 
       "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton", "InlineInputField"}}]
```

[image: demo]

This eliminates the offending input field, but it is not needed. The value that appears to right of the slider can be selected and edited. When you are done editing, click in the content pane to update it — do ***not*** hit <kbd>return</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd>.

In the second, I recommend the simpler

```
Manipulate[
  x,
  {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6, Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]